# A problem occurred configuring project ':google_maps_flutter_android' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I got a gradle related error: *A problem occurred configuring project':google_maps_flutter_android'.* When I want to build an application on the emulator, I immediately get this error. Although I did not change anything and before that everything worked fine. I did *flutter clean*, *flutter pub cache repair* - but it didn't solve my problem. What could be the problem?

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':google_maps_flutter_android'.
>
> > Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter_android-2.4.3\android\build.gradle'
> > from cache.
>
> > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':google_maps_flutter_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'] on object of type
> > org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
> > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':google_maps_flutter_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

**flutter doctor**
[image]

**error**

[image]